# Laravel Form Validation redirecting to web routes when it fails

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-10, laravel-formrequest

I have a Laravel app (v10.30.1) this api routes block:

````
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('employees', EmployeeController::class)
        ->only(['store', 'index', 'update']);
});```

This method in EmployeeController:
````

```
/**
 * Update an existing employee.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Models\Employee  $employee
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function update(EmployeeUpdateRequest $request, Employee $employee): JsonResponse
{
    $employee->update($request->validated());

    return response()->json($employee, 200);
}
```

```
This is the EmployeeUpdateRequest:
```

````
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 */
public function authorize(): bool
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'cpf' => 'required|size:11|unique:employees',
    ];
}```
````

When the validation pass, it works fine, but when it fails, instead of return the error message in a json format, it is redirecting to home web route.

If i create the Validator mannually like this, it works fine, but for now i'd need to use a form request:

````
    /**
     * Update an existing employee.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Employee  $employee
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Employee $employee): JsonResponse
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'cpf' => 'size:11|unique:employees',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 400);
        }
        $employee->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($employee, 200);
    }```

I'm expecting to use a form request and just receive the error messages when it happens instead of be redirected to web home route
````

Comment: how is the system supposed to know you don't want a redirect? how would it know this request, that you are making to an "API", should be handled in a different way?  besides the URL, what differentiates this request from any other normal web request to the application?

Comment: I am curious as to why `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['cpf'=>'size:11|unique:employees',]);` and not `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $request->rules());`

Comment: @Adi because that code doesn't use a FormRequest

Comment: Oh my apologies i assumed you must have used EmployeeUpdateRequest something like this`use App\Http\Requests\EmployeeUpdateRequest;`.

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73836381/adding-failedvalidation-function-to-request-gives-error-with-illuminate-contra? I know the problem statement is different but can you override the failedValidation method in your form request?

Comment: the answer to this is in the documentation .... what is the difference in your mind between a regular web request and an "API" request (which is just a conceptual thing)? what differentiates these 2 different things?

Comment: on a side not i am very certain this is just a duplicate and has been answered many times on here and is stated in the Laravel documentation as well

Answer (score -1):

I think if you set `Content-Type:application/json` in your header request, the problem will be solved.

Comment: It's a good practice when working with JSON, but this doesn't directly address the issue of validation errors causing a redirection and it won't directly resolve the problem here.

Comment: perhaps you mean the "accept" header? as in this request is saying it will accept a particular content type for the response

Comment: @lagbox i happened to read your deleted comment but then it would require to dig in to the middleware first making sure there is no `RedirectIfAuthenticated `, then would be to check `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to see if how validation errors are handled then check route/controller if the action return JSON on failure which is this answer. I maybe missing a few more checks but these are few out my head

Comment: its not if the action returns JSON, what the action returns doesn't matter ...  "When your application throws a `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException` exception and the incoming HTTP request is **expecting** a JSON response, Laravel will **automatically** format the error messages for you and return a 422 Unprocessable Entity HTTP response."

Comment: @lagbox yes you are correct but then doesn't it require to ensure that the routes, middleware, and controller actions are correctly configured along with api/curl request where OP can set the header to accept JSON, and there are no conflicting behavior causing the redirection. What i meant was it may or may not resolve the problem since the problem can be in any one of the following things.

Comment: @shahin The header is already set

Answer (score -1):

So per our conversation in comments and some context from here [Adding failedValidation() function to Request gives error with Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator, but passedValidation() works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73836381/adding-failedvalidation-function-to-request-gives-error-with-illuminate-contra)
Maybe you can try overriding the `failedVaidation` in your form request like this

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
    $response = new JsonResponse(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 400);
    throw new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator, $response);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Thiago Maciel this doesn't solve it? What's the error after this?